# ip v6 and ip v4 requests and trasitions

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I'm trying to understand the transition from IPv4 to IPv6.

My main question is, what if a machine using IPv6 makes a request to IPv4 service.

Can it handle it? Can a machine have both IPv6 and IPv4?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols. You usually need both to reach both.

Comment: can a personal device have both? IPv6 and IPv4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two separate protocols running independently of each other. Each packet is marked with a version number such that IPv4 and IPv6 can share the same physical link.

A machine can run both IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time, and that is the recommended configuration which all networks should have been upgraded to before IPv4 addresses ran out early 2011. Most ISPs have decided to ignore this and keep running IPv4-only providing their customers no access to IPv6. If you are a customer of such an ISP, you can get yourself a tunnel, a dual stack VPS, or both in order to get some experience with IPv6.

Translation between IPv4 and IPv6 is possible. At least one ISP have publicly stated that they will run new deployments as IPv6-only and use NAT64 to translate between the two such that their customers running IPv6-only can still reach IPv4-only servers. Other translation methods exists, but are not widespread.

Comment: so currently, devices using IPv6 can't access web services that supports IPv4?

Comment: @user1668328 That question is a bit vague. A device using IPv6 could also be using IPv4 simultaneously. A web service that supports IPv4 could also support IPv6 simultaneously. If the question was whether a device using only IPv6 can access a web service only supporting IPv4, then the answer is, that it can do so, if the ISP running the IPv6-only network has deployed a NAT64 solution.

Comment: so without the NAT64 solution, my service which runs on IPv4, can't take IPv6 requests

Comment: @user1668328 Without some translation solution, your IPv4 service cannot handle IPv6 requests. NAT64 is one of multiple possible translation solutions. When deciding on which solution is right for you, you first need to decide if translation is right for you, and whether the translation should be hosted on the client side, server side, or at a third party. Once you have decided on those questions you can decide whether NAT64 is right for you.

Comment: i have found this slideshare "NAT64 and DNS64 in 30 minutes", that helped me figuring out the ideas, and solutions that i might need (as you said- NAT64) http://www.slideshare.net/IOSHints/nat64-and-dns64-in-30-minutes